# Deploy Symfony 5 on Heroku

Tags: php, symfony, heroku, migration

I'm trying to deploy Symfony application with heroku. To do this I've followed the [official doc](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-symfony4) from Heroku.

Next , the command `git push heroku master`return me an error :
missing variable DATABASE_URL

So, I've added the ressource ClearDB to manage my app with MySQL.

In the config vars , ClearDB has added CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL , and following this [tutoriel](https://medium.com/@mallle/deploy-a-symfony-5-app-to-heroku-with-the-cleardb-mysql-addon-4df64beed9d0) , I've add DATABASE_URL with the value of CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL.

Actually I've this :

[image: config_vars]
In my Procfile, I've added release to execute command for all deploys :

```
release: php bin/console cache:clear && php bin/console cache:warmup && php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

But I got an error when I push on heroku master :

[image: error_shell]
To verify this error , I'm connecting to my DB with Sequel Pro, and the tables are presents.

I don't understand why heroku doesn't detect my last migration. For exemple in local this message is sent :

`Already at the latest version`

but not on the Heroku shell. Also , when I remove alls tables and migrate again, the message :

`There is no active transaction`

is sent, but on local I got :

`Success!`

I don't understand the differents comportements between Heroku / local shell

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: This isn't your issue, but I strongly recommend _against_ manually setting `DATABASE_URL`. ClearDB could change its URL at any time, but your application would still be using the old URL. Instead, just use `CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL` instead of `DATABASE_URL` in your Doctrine config.

Comment: But you said you connected to the database and found it empty. Do the tables exist, or not?

Comment: The table exist, mb, I don't see "select the base" after connect in sequel pro. 
When I remove table the message is "There is no active transaction" when I migrate , on local is successful". Why ? @Chris

Comment: Then please [edit] your question. It still says that your database is empty. Your question should contain all of the important information.

Comment: It's Done @Chris

Comment: Are you explicitly using transactions in your migrations? If so, please show the migration code to us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you made the migration on a different machine with a different database. You need to make the migration on the server so that it will make the necessary changes for the current database state.

Your migration is failing because it is trying to create a table `'article'` when it already exists. Therefore, your migration cannot and, should not be run.